# Does Vision API need preprocessing? Multiple QRCodes

Tags: android, computer-vision, qr-code, android-vision

I'm using mobile vision to detect **multiple** (they're usually 4+) QRCodes in images.

Will pre-processing make detection better? (binarizing the image, anything else?)

In my previous app runs I've almost never got all QRCodes in the frame, any suggestions?

Comment: Most specifications for barcodes require blank space border where no other indicia/symbols should be found. Is there a reason why all of the codes need to be in frame? My guess is that it would be faster to scan each one individually unless QRcode isn't for data transmission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Barcode API prioritizes speed over reading every single QR code that is visible, so about 3 simultaneous QR results is the rough upper limit for it will return for a single frame.

We already perform binarization, so that will not improve performance. If you have an idea of how the codes will be distributed spatially, you could try slicing the image into tiles.